# Show a text input when I choose 'other' from a select control

Tags: jquery, user-input

Please any one help me to show and hide the text box appropriately.

```
Response: 
  <label>
    <select name="call_response" id="call_response">
    <option value="No Answer">No Answer</option>
    <option value="Not Available">Not Available</option>
    <option value="Not In Use">Not In Use</option>
    <option value="On MC, PL">On MC, PL</option>
    <option value="Pending Case">Pending Case</option>
    <option value="Other">Others - To specify</option>
    </select>
  </label><br><div id="hiddendiv">
<input type="text" id="othertextbox" />
</div>
```

jQuery code:

```
$(function()
{
$("#hiddendiv").hide();
});

$("#call_response").change(function()
{
if($("#call_response").find(":selected").val($(this).val()) == "Other")
{
    $("#hiddendiv").show();
}
});

$("#othertextbox").change(function(){

$("#call_response").val($("#othertextbox").text());});
```

---

---

### Update from OP comment:

> "I try in javascript I got the answer. How I can change to jquery? Please give
>   some idea."

```
function setupScript() {
    OtherOnchanged('call_response', 'SPAN_Other', 'Other');
}
function displayNhide(display, status) {
    document.getElementById(display).style.display = status;
}
function OtherOnchanged(onChangedid, spanId, valueToCheck) {
    var value = document.getElementById(onChangedid).value;
    if (value == valueToCheck) {
        displayNhide(spanId, 'block');
    } else {
        displayNhide(spanId, 'none');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot set a `<select>`s value to something for which there is no `option` (at least with jQuery).

Add a hidden field for the *real* value, like so:

```
<label> Response:
<select name="call_response" id="call_response">
    <option value="No Answer">No Answer</option>
    <option value="Not Available">Not Available</option>
    <option value="Not In Use">Not In Use</option>
    <option value="On MC, PL">On MC, PL</option>
    <option value="Pending Case">Pending Case</option>
    <option value="Other">Others - To specify</option>
</select>
</label><br>

<input type="hidden" id="real_call_response"/>

<div id="hiddendiv">
    <input type="text" id="othertextbox"/>
</div>
```

Then activate it all with this jQuery:

```
$("#call_response").change ( function () {
    $("#real_call_response").val ( $("#call_response").val () );

    if ( $("#call_response").val ()  ==  "Other") {
        $("#hiddendiv").show().find('input').focus();
    }
    else
        $("#hiddendiv").hide();
} );

$("#othertextbox").bind ("change keypress keyup blur", function () {
    $("#real_call_response").val ( $("#othertextbox").val () );
} );
```

Note: Use CSS to hide `hiddendiv` initially.

[**See it all in action at jsFiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/w873g/1/)

---

---

### Update:

That new code, converted to jQuery is just:

```
function setupScript() {
    OtherOnchanged('call_response', 'SPAN_Other', 'Other');
}

function OtherOnchanged (onChangedId, spanId, valueToCheck) {

    if ( $("#" + onChangedId).val() ==  valueToCheck)
        $("#spanId").show ()
    else
        $("#spanId").hide ()
}
```

Comment: i try in javascript i got the answer.  How i can change to jquery?  please give some idea.                              'function setupScript(){
  OtherOnchanged('call_response','SPAN_Other','Other');
}

function displayNhide(display,status){
 document.getElementById(display).style.display = status;
}
function OtherOnchanged(onChangedid, spanId, valueToCheck){
 var value = document.getElementById(onChangedid).value;
 if(value==valueToCheck){
  displayNhide(spanId, 'block');
 }else{
  displayNhide(spanId, 'none');
 }

}'

Comment: Abi, did you see the corrected version of my answer (2 hours ago, had a typo)?  From your last comment it looks like you have figured it out.  But, if it there's still a problem, it's not clear; open a new question.

Answer (score 0):

You have the right idea, but you have a small typo.  Use the following ([working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gNkUc/2/)):

```
 $(function() {
   $("#hiddendiv").hide();
 });

 $("#call_response").change(function() {
   //EDIT: Just call val(), not val(...)
   if($("#call_response").find(":selected").val() == "Other") {
     $("#hiddendiv").show();
   }
 });

 $("#othertextbox").change(function(){

 $("#call_response").val($("#othertextbox").text());});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(function()
{
   $("#hiddendiv").hide();

  $("#call_response").change(function()
  {
    if($(this).val() == "Other")
    {
      $("#hiddendiv").show();
    }
  });

$("#othertextbox").change(function(){

   $("#call_response").val($(this).text());
});

});
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I try but i did got the answer.  how i can check the value using alert?

Comment: To alert the value use` alert($(this).val());`

Answer (score 0):

You should put your observer to the elements within the document ready event. Otherwise your observer would be useless if the dom is not ready and the dom element is not there.

```
$(function()
{
$("#hiddendiv").hide();

$("#call_response").change(function()
{
if($("#call_response").find(":selected").val($(this).val()) == "Other")
{
    $("#hiddendiv").show();
}
});

$("#othertextbox").change(function(){

$("#call_response").val($("#othertextbox").text());});

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried moving your event handler assignments inside the document ready handler? Otherwise chances are they're not finding the elements you're trying to attach them to because they're not ready yet.

```
$(function() {
  $("#hiddendiv").hide();

  $("#call_response").change(function() {
    if($("#call_response").find(":selected").val($(this).val()) == "Other") {
      $("#hiddendiv").show();
    }
  });

  $("#othertextbox").change(function(){
    $("#call_response").val($("#othertextbox").text());
  }); 

});
```